# Program crashes on opening a crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, crash

I am working on `Visual studio 2012` and I have `Crystal Report XI R2` installed on my machine. I have a `Webform App` that uses `Crystal Reports`. Problem is when I run my Application it works fine but as soon I navigate to `reports`, my program `crashes` and shows the following error

> WebDev.WebServer20.exe has stopped working
>   [image]

When I run the same program on another machine, the reports work fine. Can anybody suggest any solution?

Comment: Does it run on IIS? If so, did you checked the windows event log at administrative tools?

Comment: No its working on local